# Android. Можно ли как-то "заморозить" активность, чтобы я мог добавлять/удалять её View-хи из кода, а затем одним действием отобразить изменения?

Tags: android, activity, view, ui, android-view

Т.е. надо:

1. "Заморозить" активити
2. Провести операции с её `View`-элементами, но так, чтобы на экране при ничего не менялось в реальном времени.
3. Потом отобразить все изменения сразу.

Идеи???

Comment: RecyclerView с подходом "единого адаптера"

Comment: [ViewStub](https://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/viewstub.php)

Comment: bindable data и нотификация после всех изменений?